# how to repair Magic Eraser quartz Countertop Damage

Tags: countertops

Used a Mr clean Magic Eraser on a quartz Countertop which caused dullness to the surface. Can I bring back the shine?

Answer (score -3):

Magic eraser is like a fine sand paper, but i think you should be able to polish it back.